# show rhandsontable output based on selected date range

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am unable to use date range to selectively display rhandsontable output. When the app is run, the default values of date range are not being picked up and that is resulting in a NULL giving out error.

Please advise how I can fix this.

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(rhandsontable)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("date_range"),
      br(),
      rHandsontableOutput("hot")

    )
  )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){


  start_date <- as.Date(dmy("01-Jan-2018"), tz = "UTC")
  end_date <- as.Date(dmy("10-Jan-2018"), tz = "UTC")

  DF <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(start_date, end_date, by = 1),
                   value = 1:10, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  output$date_range <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      dateRangeInput(inputId = "dates", label = paste0("Enter Date Range"), start = start_date + 1, end = end_date - 1,
                     min = start_date, max = end_date, format = "dd-mm-yyyy")
    )
  })

  DF_selected <- reactive({
    date_vec <-DF$Date
    out <- DF[which((date_vec >= input$dates[1]) & (date_vec <= input$dates[2])),]
    return(out)
  })

  hot_mat <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$hot)){
      DF = DF_selected()
    }else{
      DF = hot_to_r(input$hot)
    }
    return(DF)
  })

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    DF_out <- hot_mat()
    rhandsontable(DF_out, useTypes = TRUE) %>% hot_col(col = 1, readOnly = TRUE)
  })

})

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){


  start_date <- as.Date(dmy("01-Jan-2018"), tz = "UTC")
  end_date <- as.Date(dmy("10-Jan-2018"), tz = "UTC")

  DF <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(start_date, end_date, by = 1),
                   value = 1:10, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  output$date_range <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      dateRangeInput(inputId = "dates", label = paste0("Enter Date Range"), start = start_date + 1, end = end_date - 1,
                     min = start_date, max = end_date, format = "dd-mm-yyyy")
    )
  })

  DF_selected <- reactive({
    date_vec <-DF$Date
    out <- DF[which((date_vec >= input$dates[1]) & (date_vec <= input$dates[2])),]
    return(out)
  })



  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    DF_out <- DF_selected()
    rhandsontable(DF_out, useTypes = TRUE) %>% hot_col(col = 1, readOnly = TRUE)
  })

})

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```